# How to use ruby protocol buffers gem to compile proto files?

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers

has anyone managed to successfully use the ['ruby protocol buffers' gem](https://github.com/codekitchen/ruby-protocol-buffers) ?
I'm having problems compiling basic proto file:

```
package Test;

message MyMessage
{
  optional string myField = 1;
}
```

when I call `ruby-protoc test.proto` I'm getting the following error message:

```
Person.proto:5:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
Person.proto:6:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.4.1/lib/protocol_buffers/compiler.rb:15:in `compile': 1 (ProtocolBuffers::CompileError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.4.1/bin/ruby-protoc:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/ruby-protoc:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/ruby-protoc:23:in `<main>'
```

Many thanks,

Tomek

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm getting this error too

Comment: I made mine Ruby module by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but in my case the problem was that I had installed the rubygem for protobuf, but I hadn't installed Google's protobuf that the rubygem relied on. 
To verify in terminal:

```
$ protoc --version
```

If "protoc: command not found", then the solution (on OSX Using homebrew) was:

```
$ brew install protoc
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

And then compiling works using your test message w/o complaints -

```
$ ruby-protoc test.proto
$
```